# Netbeans Import, Custom Library

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I'm working on a project with RS485 and for the software part we were trying to use Modbus library for it, somehow we had a problem with it (Netbeans still tried to use Java.io library instead of the Modbus IO) so we did a custom class that RXTX library and all the packages from Modbus but slightly modified so as to get it working with rxtx IO.

Then I imported de whole library to my project, but whenever I try to declare an instance of any kind of class from the library it just doesn't get it, shows an error saying sth like if the import wouldn't be there (the hint tells me to create those classes). The declarations of the imports show no errors.

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please add the actual error message to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you are developing a NetBeans platform application.

In NetBeans you can make a NetBeans library wrapper of your library jar.

You can also immediately use a module. A NetBeans module has to declare the packages that are public, for usage by others. Their module can then add a dependency, and then the import succeeds.

One problem is using the current IDE as for a module suite, especially with different versions.

Comment: yes, I think I just did something like that. the error was given because I was trying to import the jar generated in the 'dist' folder directly. now I copied it to an external folder where I keep all my libraries together. Once I imported from that path everything's running like clockwork =)